# Creating a Subclass of IdentityUser on Indentity framework .NET MVC 6,

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I have created this class to identify the users who work on a laboratory, with the lab they work on, the class extends from User, which also extends form IdentityUser.

```
namespace ASP6_SinAuth.Models
{
    [Table("Laboratory_workers")]
    public class LaboratoryWorker : User
    {
        [Column("id_lab")]
        public Laboratory? laboratory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I created a controller wuth a creation function like for a normal model:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,laboratory")] LaboratoryWorker worker,int laboratory)
        {
            if (worker.Id != null)
            {
                worker.laboratory = _context.Laboratory.Find(laboratory);
                _context.Add(worker);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error creatring the worker ");
            }
            return View(worker);
        }
```

But here comes the problem, **the instance of LaboratoryWorker is from a new User** and i dont know how to **turn a normal User instance to a LaboratoryWorker** so I can save it in the DB.

Comment: Can you provide your `Program.cs` ? Is table `LaboratoryWorker` an additional table you added or just the Custom `IdentityUser` table ？

Comment: And the code of the `Create.cshtml` view will be help us as well.

Comment: @XinranShen My program.cs is the default one I did not changed anything related to the data model, but yes `LaboratoryWorker` is a new table on the SQL server database with a FK on `User` and antother one in `Laboratory`

Comment: @Flood I did not added a the `Create.cshtml` beacause is just 2 select tags wich works fine, I captured the POST request and the data is correct.

Comment: HI , you need to provide the code of `User` , `Laboratory` and the relationship between database.